# Expectation of the absolute inner product between gaussian unit vectors

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be two  vectors with elements i.i.d drawn from standard Gaussian distribution.

They are further normalized to unite length.

Then from numerical simulations, it can be observed that

$\mathbf{E}(|\langle a,b\rangle|)\rightarrow\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi d}}$, as $d$ increases.

In fact, the convergence of the expectation begins to  be well achieved as $d$ is relatively small (on the order of tens).

Is there a way to prove the formula above?

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: "Let a,b∈Rd be two vectors with elements i.i.d drawn from standard Gaussian distribution. Let also two vectors a,b be normalized to unit length." These conditions are incompatible. Please explain.

Comment: Yes! The vector should be first generated from standard Gaussian distribution and then be normalized.